# mod_wsgi Error on CentOS 6.5

Tags: python, linux, apache, mod-wsgi

folks. I'm very new to coding and Python. This is my second Stack question ever. Apologies if I'm missing the obvious. But, I've researched this and am still stuck.

I've been trying to install and use mod_wsgi on CentOS 6.5 and am getting an error when trying to add a VirtualHost to Apache.

The mod_wsgi install seemed to go fine and my Apache status says:

Server Version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.6.6 mod_bwlimited/1.4

So, it looks to me like mod_wsgi is installed and running.

I have also added this line to the my pre-main include file for httpd.conf:

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

(I have looked ad mod_wsgi is in apache/modules.)

And, I have restarted Apache several times.

The error comes when I try to add a VirtualHost to any of the include files for https.conf.

I always get an error message that says:

Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

If I try to use a VirtualHost with a WSGIDaemonProcess reference, I get a similar error message about WSGIDaemonProcess.

From reading on Stack and other places, it sounds like I don't have mod_wsgi installed, or I don't have the Apache config file loading it, or that I haven't restarted Apache since doing those things. But, I really think I have taken all of those steps.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Marc  :-)

Comment: Could you run the following command. `openssl version -a`. If you see the line built on aug2013 or something before april 7th, you need to update your open SSL library before you continue as you are at risk. `sudo yum update openssl` will install everything you need.

Comment: Yep, I had already updated since Heartbleed. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured the out. I needed to load the module and define the VirtualHost in the same include file. I was trying to load in the first include file and define the VirtualHost in the second. Putting them both in one file kept the error from happening.